# angular - how to set div style with calculation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 4 with Angular and trying to dynamically set the height of a div this way:

```
<div class="bgsold" style="height:{{ b.qty / 100 * b.total }}%"></div>
```

So I'm getting no error or warning and the `style` property appears empty in Inspector.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any special way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[style.ATTR]` dynamic attribute to assign a dynamic value:

```
<div class="bgsold" [style.height]="(b.qty / 100 * b.total) + '%'"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

More simply you can use `[style.height.%]`:

```
[style.height.%]="(b.qty / 100 * b.total)"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

maybe you can use "ngStyle" .